# Why fopen cause page refresh?

Tags: php, http, fopen

This php code cause a redirection loop:

```
<?php

echo "TEST";
$file = fopen('test.txt', 'a');
$now = new \DateTime();
fwrite($file, $now->format('c') . "\n");
fclose($file);
```

Somehow fwrite causing the page to refresh...

Why is this happening ? How can write to file without page refresh ?

Comment: Your code is write. It is creating a file and i am neither  getting any redirection loop nor any error.

Comment: I am on windows, apache, chrome.... and you?

Comment: There has to be something else involved here.  Nothing in the above would cause a redirect.

Comment: I am on Windows

Comment: Yes.. there is something else that is causing problem. Code is right

Comment: When I run this it keeps refreshing and writing the times to the file... I am clueless...

Comment: Code is fine but still you can debug each line put die() after each line and you will find the culprit line, but your code is right.

Comment: I know... it stop refreshing if I remove the fwrite command....

Comment: It was a google-chrome issue... [http://superuser.com/questions/1048029/disable-auto-refresh-tabs-in-chrome-desktop](http://superuser.com/questions/1048029/disable-auto-refresh-tabs-in-chrome-desktop)